# Error in Django 2.0 tutorial, part 7 -- is this a bug?

Tags: django

When I follow the 2.0 tutorial, on part 7, I noticed there is an error icon under "PUBLISHED RECENTLY" in this screenshot:

[image]

The "was_published_attribute" was set to True in the tutorial. But if set it to False, it can show "False" correctly, as in below:
[image]

The related code is in the polls/models.py,

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ... ...   
    def was_published_recently(self):
        ... ...
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = False
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
```

What I changed is the line `was_published_recently.boolean = False`. Again it shows the little on/off icons with the attribute initialized as `True`, and shows the text "True/False" with the attribute initialized as `False`.

Is this a bug? Any suggestion of fixing? Many thanks!

I apologize that I describe this question poorly in the title. I appreciate it if anyone can suggest me a better title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It's not a bug, it's a feature". Quote from django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

> If the string given is a method of the model, ModelAdmin or a callable that returns True or False Django will display a pretty “on” or “off” icon if you give the method a boolean attribute whose value is True.

So when you add `was_published_attribute.boolean = True` into admin class django will replace words False and True with  red or green image. So in your case error symbol is just indicator that actual value of `was_published_attribute` is false. Try to create new record with `was_published_attribute=True` and you will see pretty green sign instead of error symbol for this new object.

Comment: Not exactly. If change it to "was_published_attribute=False" in the code, it shows the text "False", not an image. I am talking about latest Django 2.0.

Comment: @Luke can you add code? And show where you put True? `was_published_attribute` is dynamic field in tutorial.

Comment: Hi friend, sorry I was interrupted earlier today. I now edited the question with the images and the code. Hope it clarifies my issue.

Comment: @Luke as I said you dont sctually set value of was_published_recently, you just say to django that this fied is boolean. `was_published_recently.boolean = False`.  And for boolean field django will add icon instead of text. Actual value never changed. It is false.

Comment: Exactly. The initial value shouldn't matter, but here it changed the display. True, shows the icons; False, shows the text "True" or "False".

Comment: Oh, I know what you say. Thanks a lot.